# tshark returns 0 results for filter icmp.no_resp but wireshark returns 12 resutls with the same filter

Tags: wireshark, tshark, wireshark-dissector

I am trying to do packet capture analysis with tshark on about 30000 files looking for a needle in the haystack.The files containing interesting needles contain icmp failures. I wrote a script which iterates though these files with tshark but they all return 0 results.

```
tshark -r <filename> -Y "icmp.no_resp"
tshark -r <filename> -Y "icmp.resp_not_found"
```

Both ofthese commands yield 0 results. However when I open a specific file and use the display filter "icmp.no_resp" or "icmp.resp_not_found" I see results.

Is this a bug in T-shark where it can't identify response not found?

I'm running tshark/wireshark v3.6.7 on Ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.
tshark requires multiple passes to identify certain display filters. Doing a command like so creates this.

```
tshark -r <filename> -Y "icmp.resp_not_found" -2
```

I hope this helps someone in the future.

Comment: Hi, found your comment helpful. Do you know how I can extract whether an icmp response has been received or not into a csv/txt file e.g.

ip_src                 icmp_resp_status
192.168.1.10      0
192.170.3.21      1